# Updating the Moto G 3rd gen from Lollipop 5.1.1 to Marshmallow 6.0.1

Tags: updates, 6.0-marshmallow, 5.1-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, motorola-moto-g3

I'm on a UK Moto G, 3rd gen, 8GB storage, 1GB memory, currently on Android 5.1.1.

I have numerously been prompted to update to 6.0. The 6.0 on Moto G 3rd gen has some bugs, like the shutter sound cannot be disabled. So I am ignoring the notifications, and have remained on 5.1.1.

How come I am being constantly prompted to update to the buggy 6.0 instead of the rectified 6.0.1?

---

<s>Update: I have now updated to 6.0. However, when I go to About Phone and check for new OS software, I am being prompted that my software is already up-to-date. This is contrary to [this Moto UK website](https://motorola-global-en-uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/110389/p/30,6720,9390). Restarting did not help. How can I update to 6.0.1?</s>
[This has been posted as a new question.](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145703/39058)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How come I am being constantly prompted to update to the buggy 6.0 instead of the rectified 6.0.1?

It depends upon the manufacturer pushing the update. For many number of devices you would end up in same situation even if the first release of a platform upgrade was buggy. Let's take it this way:

Assume that these are the Android versions - build numbers for your device:

Android 5.1.1: build LJKRTY;
Android 6.0.: build MOUIPV;
Android 6.0.1: build MOUIPW

When you would switch from build LJKRTY to MOUIPV a lot of the files  required for Android 6.0 would be upgraded. Since the manufacturer came to know about a couple of bugs in the recent release, *they decided to only patch the bugs and release the patch as an update with build MOUIPW instead of packing and releasing the whole platform upgrade again.*

Now there is no point in applying a patch if at the first place both the vulnerable and relevant code isn't there. You may also not be able to apply such a patch manually since manufacturer can require an update to check whether the currently installed build is compatible.

So over and all, switch from Android 5.1.1 to 6.0. and then to 6.0.1. That's the way to go.

By the way, it is possible that the update for 6.0.1 may be a full blown platform upgrade but your software updater is stuck at 6.0 simply because it is silly. You can attempt to clear its data (if it is a separate app), force stop it (or reboot) and attempt to check if it still requires to download Android 6.0. I won't keep hope here.

Comment: I have now updated to 6.0. However, when I go to About Phone and check for new OS software, I am being prompted that my software is already up-to-date. Restarting did not help. I just edited my question to point out that this is a UK Moto G, if that is relevant. Do you know how I can update to 6.0.1?

Comment: Your original question was "*How come I am being constantly prompted to update to the buggy 6.0 instead of the rectified 6.0.1?*" and I've addressed that alone. Your new update in question is not in consonance with your original question but can suffice as a new question.

Comment: Agreed. I have created a new question. http://android.stackexchange.com/q/145703/39058