# Android not updating from 6.0 to 6.0.1 for Moto G 3rd gen

Tags: updates, 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g3

So...

- Moto G3 2015 from UK, purchased as carrier independent
- XT1541
- Current system version 24.41.33.osprey_retgb.retgb.en.GB retgb

According to the official Moto UK website, Android 6.0.1 was made available to the Moto G3 months ago.

> https://motorola-global-en-uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/110389/p/30,6720,9390

I have been on 6.0 (it's not called 6.0.0) for AGES but there are no notifications to update to 6.0.1.

Tried:

- Factory reset
- Cleared cache through recovery

### Didn't. Help.

When I go to About Phone and check for new OS software, I am being prompted that my software (6.0) is already up-to-date. This is contrary to [the Moto UK website](https://motorola-global-en-uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/110389/p/30,6720,9390).

It doesn't help knowing that all my acquaintances using the G3 had been automatically upgraded to 6.0.1 AGES ago.

### How can I upgrade my Moto G3 from 6.0 to 6.0.1?

Comment: I started a parallel topic [here on Moto-Lenovo forums.](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/MOTO-G-3rd-Gen/Moto-G3-not-updating-from-Android-6-0-to-Android-6-0-1/td-p/3386562)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the discussion on the official Moto forum, it seems that the updates are inconsistent.

USA devices are all on 6.0.
Indian devices are all on 6.0.1.
European devices are inconsistently on 6.0 and 6.0.1, even though the devices may be from the same country, purchased SIM free from retail, and on the same network.

Source
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/MOTO-G-3rd-Gen/Moto-G3-not-updating-from-Android-6-0-to-Android-6-0-1/td-p/3386562

Comment: UPDATE UPDATE!!! It is confirmed now that Moto is slowly pushing the update. Comment on their thread here and pressurise them to roll out faster!!! https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/MOTO-G-3rd-Gen/Moto-G3-not-updating-from-Android-6-0-to-Android-6-0-1/m-p/3488829#M7865

Comment: One of my phones STILL has 6.0 while the other one is on 6.0.1. This is very frustrating. There are also different security patch levels on the phones that are on 6.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

OTA updates are typically incremental... 6.0.1 can only be installed over 6.0.0, and 6.0.0 can only be installed over 5.1.1, and typically more than just version has to match, the exact build number must match as well. You will not be prompted to install the 6.0.1 update until you are running the 6.0.0 update. If you want to completely skip 6.0.0, then you will have to manually flash the 6.0.1 image which will wipe all data from the device.

Comment: Yes I am already on 6.0 (it's not called 6.0.0). I'll edit my question and make the 6.0 more eye-catchy.

Comment: @SumanKrishnaSaha Have you tried clearing the cache through recovery?

Comment: I have cleared the cache through recovery. Didn't help. I also did a factory reset. Didn't help. Would you have any more ideas please?

Comment: What is the exact model and variant? We know that Moto started rolling out 6.0.1 to some Moto G 2015 devices earlier this year, then stopped the rollout with no indication as to why or for how long it would be until it continued. XT1541, XT1543, XT1548, and XT1550 did get 6.0.1, with some caveats... the XT1541 only got 6.0.1 on the retail and Three UK variants, the Tesco UK, Vodaphone UK, and O2 UK variants did not and still only have 6.0.0, just as examples

Comment: it's at Moto G3 2015 from UK, more specifically a XT1541 sim-free from Carphone Warehouse. Would you perhaps know about this?

Comment: @SumanKrishnaSaha Where you actually purchased it from isn't relevant, the variant does. Go to Settings - About Phone... What is the full System Version displayed?

Comment: 24.41.33.osprey_retgb.retgb.en.GB retgb

Comment: @SumanKrishnaSaha that is the retail version, should get 6.0.1... Have you tried removing your SIM when on WiFi and checking for updates? If that fails, you could just flash the stock firmware image.

Comment: No SIM and Wi-Fi didn't help. Not comfortable with flashing the stock firmware image. On a related note, I started a parallel topic [here on Moto-Lenovo forums.](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/MOTO-G-3rd-Gen/Moto-G3-not-updating-from-Android-6-0-to-Android-6-0-1/td-p/3386562)